# Error while giving ajax and jquery.post call in IIS

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

While givin ajax or jquery.post call in IIS its going to error block. But the same is working locally. Not able to find the issue. Please help.

Iam using MVC3. On button click am trying to give an ajax call.In the controller, I have written a try-catch block which should catch the error and so it should not go to the error block of ajax. But in the deployed version its going to the ajax error block where as Iam not facing any error while running it locally.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please check the updates.

Comment: Are you using CORS request? and We understand your problem that your code doesn't work in deployed environment. As of now whatever solution is provided will be based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not using CORS.

I was passing the grid values in the url. Instead of passing it in url when I gave it in the data parameter of ajax its worked fine. I think its because of the length limitation.

This issue is fixed!

@ Thanks Satpal for your help!